# FactoryGirl unable to create factory object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I've got a unusual behavior while trying to create my user object, this is a factory bit for my user :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    firstname "Firstname"
    sequence(:surname)  { |n| "#{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user_#{n}@test.com"}
    password "pwdddddd"
    dob Time.zone.now - 19.years
    phone "432423432431"
  end
end
```

And I have one of my tests :

```
describe 'just an ordinary test' do
   let(:user) { build(:user) }
 end
```

Test fails with this error :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: User can't be blank
```

So I added this code in hope that I will get more info on the error :

```
let(:user) { 
        begin 
          build(:user) 
        rescue => e
          puts "error: #{e.inspect}"
        end
      }
```

I get this :

```
error: #<ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User can't be blank>
```

Which is not really helpful. How can a validation of a user can be `user can't be blank`.

My head hurts from this one, any similar experiences?

Comment: In the line ````let(:user) { build(:user }```` you don't close the bracket after user. Is it a typo or the problem ?

Comment: @FredPerrin thanks for noticing that, unfortunately that is just me being lousy typer, it's not the case with the issue I'm having. Thanks for the tip I edited the question

Comment: Could you add you model and validations? One other thing : only one ````end```` at the end of your Factory definition.

Comment: @FredPerrin I don't have any validations that is my point, thanks I've updated missing end as well

Comment: try commenting out `dob Time.zone.now - 19.years` for the time being, I've had errors having `2.days` `3.hours` etc in factories

Comment: @SuckerForMayhem thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it's the same

Comment: Have you tried user.errors.full_messages (or something similar) to see which attribute is in error ?

Comment: I think we need your schema senor.

Comment: Do you have some other factory for a model which has `validates :user, presence: true` and is used in the specs somewhere?